# Users Registration on POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, registration

I am using devise to do my user registration

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations:  'users/registrations',
                                      :sessions => "users/sessions",
                                      :passwords => 'users/passwords',
                                      :confirmations => 'users/confirmations'
  }
  authenticate :user do
    namespace :users do
      post '/sign_up', :to => 'registrations#new'
    end 
  end
```

and i want to go to **users/sign_up** as a post 
but when i get there it take me to the **users/sing_in**
what should i do?

Answer (score 2):

You need to point the post action at `registrations#create` rather than `new`.

Comment: thanks but it still does the name thing. it takes me to the users/sing_in, instead if the users/sign_up. I even changed the route to have a name    

post '/sign_up', :to => 'registrations#create', :as => 'post_sing_up'

Comment: `new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)            users/registrations#new` I want to go to that this route as a post

Comment: Why are you creating these routes? Devise creates all the routes automatically. If you run `rake routes` it should include the `POST` route for `user_registration`, that's the one you want - it leads to the create action.

Comment: Well i am getting redirected from another site that is passing a POST instead of a GET. but i still want to post that page

Comment: `cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)             users/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                    users/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)            users/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)               users/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                    users/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                    users/registrations#destroy` there are all my routes

Comment: It's right there: `user_registration POST /users(.:format) users/registrations#create` That's the post that creates a new user, is that not what you need? Devise will make all your routes, controllers and views automatically, if this doesn't help, tell us what you're trying to do (update your question with more info) and I'll do my best to help.

Comment: Thanks for the help, What i ended up doing was sending the request to a bs page, saving the params, and redirection to the right page on the site.